# Return DataTable row values onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have been studying and working endlessly with DataTables the past 2 weeks and gotten to a brick wall now. The issue I am trying to sort out is how I can pass values in a particular row when the button for that row is clicked on. As at now with my limited knowledge on DataTables and JQuery, when I have like 2 to 3 buttons in different rows and I click on each one, the value they all return back is the values in the first row only. Not sure how best I can solve this or where my error might lie. Any guide or help would be much appreciated. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

<!-- ------------------- Extract all Alerts ---------------------- -->
    $(document).ready(function (){
        var alertTable = $('#alert-table').DataTable({
            "jQueryUI": true,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "source", "visible": false },
                { "data": "host" },
                { "data": "description" },
                { "data": "priority" },
                { "data": "acknowledged", render: function( data, type, row ) {
                    if (data == "0" && row.priority > "2") {return '<div><form method="post" id="'+row.source + row.eventid+'" action="include/db_conn.php"> <input type="hidden"  id="evtid" value ="'+row.eventid+'"> <input type="hidden"  name="source" value ="'+row.source+'"> <INPUT TYPE="text" name="username" size="3" maxlength="3"> <input type="submit" name="'+row.source + row.eventid+'" onClick="ackbutton(this)" value="Ack Alert"></form></div>';
                    } return data;
                    }
                }
            ],
        });

        setInterval (function(){
            $.getJSON("data/json_data.txt", function (pcheckdata){

                alertTable.clear().draw();
                alertTable.rows.add(pcheckdata.alert).draw();
                alertTable.columns.adjust().draw();
            });
        }, 10000);
    });

        function ackbutton() {
            //e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            var getvalues = $('#evtid').val();
            alert(getvalues);
        }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="all_tables">
        <table id="alert-table" class="display" cellspacing="0">
            <thead class="t-headers">
                <tr>
                    <th>Server</th>
                    <th>Host</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Acknowledged</th>
                    <th>Eventid</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

JSON

```
{
    "alert": [
        {
            "source": "Server1",
            "host": "host1",
            "description": "Engine Alive",
            "priority": "4",
            "triggerid": "14531",
            "acknowledged": "0",
            "eventid": "3419709",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "source": "Server2",
            "host": "host2",
            "description": "webapp down",
            "priority": "2",
            "triggerid": "18027",
            "acknowledged": "1",
            "eventid": "4012210",
            "value": "1"
        }
    ],

    "error": []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the input with id 'evtid' in closest div of currently clicked ack button.

Example:

```
$(document).on('click','.submitButton',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
        debugger
          var $this = $(this);
        var curEventId = $this.closest('div').find('#evtid');
        var getvalues = curEventId.val();
        alert(getvalues);
 return false;

});
```

You can also use closest form instead of div.

> var curEventId = $this.closest('form').find('#evtid');

Comment: Hi SSA, thanks for the response. I will try this out but I just noticed that data changes aren't picked up even after it refreshes. This was working so not sure what I have done to stop it working

Comment: As I see in your code, you do clear the table and redraw it with new data, this should work fine, until there is an error in browser console. Check for console errors. F12. best way to verify whats going on is set a breakpoint in render function and around the functions which clears and redraws the table.

Comment: Hi, the refresh issue strangely was my browser cache. Cleared it and it started updating - strange. I have tried both suggestions but getting **undefined** result

Comment: Can you show the html generated? or create a short fiddler example out of it.

Comment: Sorry SSA, how do I create a Fiddle with an external JSON data? I have added the html and json to case. Thanks

Comment: No worries I created one, http://jsfiddle.net/euryqcrf/31/ , check it, it gives correct eventid when you click it.

Comment: Just one more, how do I pass the value in the textbox

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60820/discussion-between-ssa-and-chelseawillrecover).